# Pandas lagged rolling average on aggregate data with multiple groups and missing dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, rolling-computation

I'd like to calculate a lagged rolling average on a complicated time-series dataset.  Consider the toy example as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(101)

fruit = ['apples', 'apples', 'apples', 'oranges', 'apples', 'oranges', 'oranges',
         'oranges', 'apples', 'oranges', 'apples', 'apples']
people = ['alice']*6+['bob']*6
date = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-11', '2022-01-11',
         '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-20', '2022-01-20', '2022-01-25']
count = np.random.poisson(4,size=12)
weight_per = np.round(np.random.uniform(1,3,size=12),2)

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':date, 'people':people, 'fruit':fruit,
                   'count':count, 'weight':weight_per*count})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

This results in the following DataFrame:

```
    date        people  fruit   count   weight
0   2022-01-01  alice   apples  2       2.72
1   2022-01-03  alice   apples  6       11.28
2   2022-01-04  alice   apples  5       13.80
3   2022-01-04  alice   oranges 3       8.70
4   2022-01-11  alice   apples  2       3.92
5   2022-01-11  alice   oranges 3       5.76
6   2022-01-04  bob     oranges 8       18.16
7   2022-01-05  bob     oranges 5       8.25
8   2022-01-05  bob     apples  5       6.20
9   2022-01-20  bob     oranges 4       4.40
10  2022-01-20  bob     apples  2       4.56
11  2022-01-25  bob     apples  2       5.24
```

Now I'd like to add a column representing the average weight per fruit for the previous 7 days: `wgt_per_frt_prev_7d`.  It should be defined as the sum of all the fruit weights divided by the sum of all the fruit counts for the past 7 days, not including the current day.  While there are many ways to brute force this answer, I'm looking for something with relatively good time complexity.  If I were to calculate this column by hand, these would be the calculations and expected results:

```py
df['wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = np.nan

df.loc[1, 'wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = 2.72/2 # row 0

df.loc[2, 'wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = (2.72+11.28)/(2+6) # row 0 and 1
df.loc[3, 'wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = (2.72+11.28)/(2+6)

df.loc[4, 'wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = (8.70+13.80+6.20+8.25+18.16)/(3+5+5+5+8) # row 2,3,6,7,8
df.loc[5, 'wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = (8.70+13.80+6.20+8.25+18.16)/(3+5+5+5+8)

df.loc[6, 'wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = (2.72+11.28)/(2+6) # row 0,1

df.loc[7, 'wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = (8.70+13.80+2.72+11.28+18.16)/(3+5+6+2+8) # row 0,1,2,3,6
df.loc[8, 'wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = (8.70+13.80+2.72+11.28+18.16)/(3+5+6+2+8)

df.loc[11, 'wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = (4.40+4.56)/(2+4) # row 9,10
```

Final DF:

```
    date        people  fruit   count   weight  wgt_per_frt_prev_7d
0   2022-01-01  alice   apples  2       2.72    NaN
1   2022-01-03  alice   apples  6       11.28   1.360000
2   2022-01-04  alice   apples  5       13.80   1.750000
3   2022-01-04  alice   oranges 3       8.70    1.750000
4   2022-01-11  alice   apples  2       3.92    2.119615
5   2022-01-11  alice   oranges 3       5.76    2.119615
6   2022-01-04  bob     oranges 8       18.16   1.750000
7   2022-01-05  bob     oranges 5       8.25    2.277500
8   2022-01-05  bob     apples  5       6.20    2.277500
9   2022-01-20  bob     oranges 4       4.40    NaN
10  2022-01-20  bob     apples  2       4.56    NaN
11  2022-01-25  bob     apples  2       5.24    1.493333
```

EDIT

The final column I'd like to add is `wgt_per_apl_prev_7d`, which only considers the apple weights when calculating this field, but still applies to all rows, even rows with just oranges.  The output of this calculation should be as follows:

```
    date        people  fruit   count   weight  wgt_per_frt_prev_7d wgt_per_apl_prev_7d
0   2022-01-01  alice   apples  2       2.72    NaN                NaN
1   2022-01-03  alice   apples  6       11.28   1.360000      1.360000
2   2022-01-04  alice   apples  5       13.80   1.750000      1.750000
3   2022-01-04  alice   oranges 3       8.70    1.750000      1.750000
4   2022-01-11  alice   apples  2       3.92    2.119615      2.000000
5   2022-01-11  alice   oranges 3       5.76    2.119615      2.000000
6   2022-01-04  bob     oranges 8       18.16   1.750000      1.750000
7   2022-01-05  bob     oranges 5       8.25    2.277500      2.138462
8   2022-01-05  bob     apples  5       6.20    2.277500      2.138462
9   2022-01-20  bob     oranges 4       4.40    NaN                NaN
10  2022-01-20  bob     apples  2       4.56    NaN                NaN
11  2022-01-25  bob     apples  2       5.24    1.493333      2.280000
```

Comment: `df.loc[11, 'wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = (4.40+4.56)/(4+2) # row 9,10`

Comment: Then my answer provides the same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df2 = df[['date', 'count', 'weight']].groupby('date').sum()
df2 = df2.rolling('8D').apply(np.sum, raw=True) - df2
df = df.merge((df2['weight']/df2['count']).rename('avg').to_frame().reset_index(), on='date', how='left')

df2 = df[df['fruit'] == 'apples'][['date', 'count', 'weight']].groupby('date').sum()
df2 = df2.rolling('8D').apply(np.sum, raw=True) - df2
df = df.merge((df2['weight']/df2['count']).rename('avg_apple').to_frame().reset_index(), on='date', how='left')
```

Output

```
    date        people  fruit   count   weight  avg        avg_apple
0   2022-01-01  alice   apples  2       2.72    NaN        NaN
1   2022-01-03  alice   apples  6       11.28   1.360000   1.360000
2   2022-01-04  alice   apples  5       13.80   1.750000   1.750000
3   2022-01-04  alice   oranges 3       8.70    1.750000   1.750000
4   2022-01-11  alice   apples  2       3.92    2.119615   2.000000
5   2022-01-11  alice   oranges 3       5.76    2.119615   2.000000
6   2022-01-04  bob     oranges 8       18.16   1.750000   1.750000
7   2022-01-05  bob     oranges 5       8.25    2.277500   2.138462
8   2022-01-05  bob     apples  5       6.20    2.277500   2.138462
9   2022-01-20  bob     oranges 4       4.40    NaN        NaN
10  2022-01-20  bob     apples  2       4.56    NaN        NaN
11  2022-01-25  bob     apples  2       5.24    1.493333   2.280000
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer works and is pretty fast.  For a dataframe of 10k rows, it still averages at 7 ms on my machine.  Would it be possible to extend this answer to calculate results for the "apples-only" edit that I added to the initial question?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

np.random.seed(101)

fruit = ['apples', 'apples', 'apples', 'oranges', 'apples', 'oranges', 'oranges',
         'oranges', 'apples', 'oranges', 'apples', 'apples']
people = ['alice']*6+['bob']*6
date = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-11', '2022-01-11',
         '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-20', '2022-01-20', '2022-01-25']
count = np.random.poisson(4,size=12)
weight_per = np.round(np.random.uniform(1,3,size=12),2)

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':date, 'people':people, 'fruit':fruit,
                   'count':count, 'weight':weight_per*count})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['date_ini'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x - datetime.timedelta(days=8))
df['wgt_per_frt_prev_7d'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[(df['date'] > x['date_ini']) & (df['date'] < x['date'])]['weight'].sum()/df[(df['date'] > x['date_ini']) & (df['date'] < x['date'])]['count'].sum() if df[(df['date'] > x['date_ini']) & (df['date'] < x['date'])]['count'].sum()>0 else np.nan, axis=1)
df = df.drop('date_ini', axis=1)
df
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it does produce the correct results.  However, it's very slow, and does not scale well at larger dataframe sizes.  On my machine, it averages 126 ms for a dataframe of 100 rows, and seems to scale linearly with n_rows (which I believe is typical of `apply` methods).  However, this time could likely be improved with numba or cython